# Prevent SASS parsing block of code but still output it to final css file

Tags: css, sass

I've just started using SASS. Very impressed, however there is something I'd like to do but can't seem to find answer as whether or not it's possible.

I have a block of CSS that I don't want SASS to parse/compile but I would still like that block outputting to the final compiled CSS file. Is this possible?

Thanks.

My first ever SO question, normally provides the answer. Hope I've not missed it somewhere, tried every search term I could think of to find it.

Comment: Example? Not sure why you would want to preserve CSS, instead just convert it to SASS syntax

Comment: I was getting a SASS error which I initially attributed to SASS having trouble with my CSS (that I knew to be valid/good) so at that point I was hoping there is a way to write code in a scss file that doesn't get parsed but still gets outputted to the resultant CSS file.

My issue was incorrectly using the @import feature of SASS within my Jekyll work flow. In Jekyll you need YAML "Front-matter" at the start of any files you want processed by Jekyll however it's not required in a SASS Partial because they are not processed by Jekyll. So I didn't know SASS was erroring at the YAML front-matter.

Comment: I currently no longer need an answer to this question but I will leave open as somebody else might?

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a separate .css file and import it in your SASS file. File ending in .css are not parsed but are still included in the final output.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit old, but, in the spirit of keeping things up-to-date:

The current version of SASS (3.4.22) does a pretty good job of only changing what it needs to.  If what you've written is valid CSS, it should output as is.

The only times you should see SASS modifying your styles is if you've done something that looks like it's supposed to be modified.  Based on their documentation, that would be things like:

- Nesting styles
- Concatenating strings

  - `content: 'foo' + 'bar';`
- Using interpolation

  - `left: calc(50% - #{$variable})`
- Using variables

  - `width: $variable`
- Using `@extend` or nesting an `@include`

In most other situations, in my experience, SASS will happily spit out whatever you've written.

If you do need to output something that SASS insists on parsing when it doesn't need to, you can wrap the offending piece in quotes and remove them using the `unquote` function:

```
$family: unquote("Droid+Sans");
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=#{$family}");
```

which compiles to

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to enclose your block in /* ..... */ in your scss file. Hope it helps.

Comment: I looked at commenting. That doesn't quite do what I wanted. That does indeed output to the final css file but it's commented-out still which is not what I want.

Essentially my problem is I want some CSS outputting to the final file but not parsed by SASS.